# Downgrade to python 3.6.5 with brew: Error /bin/sh: sphinx-build: command not found make: *** [build] Error 127

Tags: python, python-3.6, downgrade

Please, I'm downgrading to Python 3.6.5 using brew, but I got this error:

Command:

```
brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

Error:

```
mkdir -p build
Using existing Misc/NEWS file
PATH=./venv/bin:$PATH sphinx-build -b html -d build/doctrees -D latex_elements.papersize=  . build/html 
/bin/sh: sphinx-build: command not found
make: *** [build] Error 127

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

These open issues may also help:
Python 3.7.2 install fails https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/36753
pagmo: build with python binding https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/36445
python@2: fix zlib with CLT on 10.14 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/34562
```

Can someone help me?

PS: Xcode is already installed, I run `brew unlink python` (to unlink 3.7), `sphinx-build` is on `/usr/local/bin/sphinx-build`.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes. I have marked as solution now. I have started use pyenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brew formula for 3.6.5 has some issues. Here is a [open](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25093) issue on github about this error.

I have decided to change to [pyenv](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/manage-multiple-python-versions-and-virtual-environments-venv-pyenv-pyvenv-a29fb00c296f) with pyenv-virtualenv in order to avoid using `brew switch python 3.xx` all time.

As I need to use many different installations of Python on the same machine, 2.7 and 3.4 for example and many virtual environments, just brew swicth and virtualenv is not working well.

Answer (score 0):

See [python.rb formula for 3.6.8](https://gist.github.com/SamuelMarks/0ceaaf6d3de12b6408e3e67aae80ae3b)

Step-by-step instructions, with transcript, in my comment in fork:

I had to leave in, that is ***not*** comment out the

`depends_on sphinx-doc" => :build`

to build from source as detailed in my fork comment:

[gisthub dukechem fork of python.rb formula for 3.6.8](https://gist.github.com/dukechem/ef5cb77d0b571eb0f794a4be821bd53c#gistcomment-2989118)